# «Ко мне в гости», «к себе в отдел» — почему не выделяются уточняющие обороты?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

И вообще, уточняющие ли обороты это?

Comment: Приведите примеры, так никто не будет знать, о чем вы.

Comment: «Сегодня приду к тебе в гости», «с радостью возьму к себе в отдел».